# PCL Instantiating new Point Types for all Functions

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have declared a new point type as such below. However, I need it to work with all available PCL functions. Such as segmentation, voxel grid etc. It is a pain to include all the implementation headers do the PCL_INSTANTIATE call. Is there anyway to do this for all major functions? For example, compile my point type for all functions in the segmentation library?

```
    #define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE

#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/impl/instantiate.hpp>

#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp>
#include <pcl/search/impl/kdtree.hpp>

#include <pcl/octree/octree_search.h>
#include <pcl/octree/impl/octree_search.hpp>

#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/impl/sac_segmentation.hpp>

struct FeaturePoint
{
    PCL_ADD_POINT4D;
    PCL_ADD_RGB;
    PCL_ADD_NORMAL4D;

    static const int DESCRIPTOR_SIZE = 128;
    float descriptor[DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];

    FeaturePoint() {}
    FeaturePoint(const FeaturePoint& input)
    {
        this->x = input.x;
        this->y = input.y;
        this->z = input.z;
        this->rgb = input.rgb;
        this->normal_x = input.normal_x;
        this->normal_y = input.normal_y;
        this->normal_z = input.normal_z;
        for(int i = 0; i < DESCRIPTOR_SIZE; ++i) { this->descriptor[i] = input.descriptor[i]; } // Ugly, as I was lazy
    }

    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
} EIGEN_ALIGN16;

POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (FeaturePoint,
                                   (float, x, x)
                                   (float, y, y)
                                   (float, z, z)
                                   (float, rgb, rgb)
                                   (float, normal_x, normal_x)
                                   (float, normal_y, normal_y)
                                   (float, normal_z, normal_z)
                                   (float, descriptor, descriptor)
);

PCL_INSTANTIATE(KdTree, FeaturePoint);
PCL_INSTANTIATE(KdTreeFLANN, FeaturePoint);
PCL_INSTANTIATE(OctreePointCloudSearch, FeatureP
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS DOESN'T WORK!!

---

Instead of using

`PCL_INSTANTIATE(function,template);`

try

`PCL_INSTANTIATE_PointCloud(template);`

I hope it helps. I was 2 day looking for this solution.

Comment: What exactly does this do? Do I still have to include the impl headers/files?

Comment: I just tried it and I still get undefined references

Comment: After try with all functions, still doesn't works.
What version of PCL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: After trying solutions for hours this works correctly for all functions:

Representative part of code in PCLapp.h:

```
include pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h
include pcl-1.8/pcl/point_types.h
include pcl-1.8/pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h
include boost/shared_ptr.hpp

namespace pcl{

struct PointXYZIR
  {
    PCL_ADD_POINT4D                     // Macro quad-word XYZ
    float intensity;                    // Laser intensity
    uint16_t ring;                      // Laser ring number
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW     // Ensure proper alignment
  } EIGEN_ALIGN16;
}

POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT(PointXYZIR,
                                  (float, x, x)
                                  (float, y, y)
                                  (float, z, z)
                                  (float, intensity, intensity)
                                  (uint16_t, ring, ring)
)


typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIR> PointCloudXYZIR;

### I didn't include any .hpp file (like tutorial said)
```

Representative part of code in PCLapp.cpp (VoxelGrid example)

```
boost::shared_ptr<PointCloudXYZIR> input_cloud(new PointCloudXYZIR);
PointCloudXYZIR::ConstPtr input_cloudPtr(input_cloud);

pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZIR> vox;
vox.setInputCloud(input_cloudPtr);
vox.setLeafSize(0.05,0.05,0.05);
vox.filter(*input_cloud);
```

And this works perfectly with all filters without doing anything more.